# php prevent big float rounding

Tags: php

Here is a simple code with PHP:

```
$v = 999999999999.99999;
var_dump($v, strval($v), intval($v), floatval($v), sprintf('%.53f', $v));
```

Output is:

```
float(1000000000000)
string(13) "1000000000000"
int(1000000000000)
float(1000000000000)
string(67) "1000000000000.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Can I get an original value from this variable before rounding?

Comment: try https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Answer (score 0):

Like @iłya-bursov mentioned, use BC math library.

You supply your number in string format but you can do math operations on them.

```
$v = '999999999999.99999';
echo bcadd($v, 0, 5);
// 999999999999.99999

echo bcadd($v, $v, 5);
// 1999999999999.99998
```